# Laravel contact form is not working correctly

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with the Laravel site's form, when I send the form through the site it shows an error, using devTools it is noted that it is an error 500 of the Post method, but the form is sent anyway.

the following error appears in the laravel log file

> [2021-12-15 11:27:49] production.ERROR: Missing required parameters for [Route: contato] [URI: {lang}/contato]. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException(code: 0): Missing required parameters for [Route: contato] [URI: {lang}/contato]. at /home/corstonecom/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Exceptions/UrlGenerationException.php:17)

In the form view it like this:

```
<form id="frm-contato" class="site-form" action="{{ route('contato-enviar', app()->getLocale()) }}" method="post">
```

In the routes file web.php it like this:

```
Route::view('/contato', 'fale-conosco')->name('contato');

Route::post('/contato', 'HomeController@enviarContato')->name('contato-enviar');
```

and in the controller it like this:

```
public function enviarContato(EnviaContatoRequest $request)

{
    
    $inputs  = $request->all();

    $inputs['localidade'] = $inputs['cidade'] . '/' . $inputs['uf'];

    $contato = Contatos::create($inputs);



    Lead::fastSave([

        'name'  => $inputs['nome'],

        'email' => $inputs['email'],

    ]);



    Mail::send(new FaleConosco($contato));

    Session::flash('contato_enviado', 'sucesso');

    return redirect()->route('contato');
    

}
```

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to pass the `lang` parameter when calling the `route` method when doing the redirect in your Controller method as the route `contato` requires the `lang` parameter:

```
return redirect()->route('contato', ['lang' => app()->getLocale()]);
```

It is best to get in the habit of using an associative array for the parameters as any more than 1 parameter and they will need to be in an associative array for the URL generator to match them up.

If you don't want to have to constantly be passing this `app()->getLocale()` value to the URL helpers you can set a default for the `lang` parameter and it will be added for you. You could use a middleware to do this. Example of the functionality of setting a default value for a parameter:

```
public function handle($request, $next)
{
    \URL::defaults([
        'lang' => app()->getLocale(),
    ]);

    return $next($request);
}
```

Now you don't have to pass the parameter for `lang` when generating URLs as it has a default value set.

If you already have a "locale" middleware that is handling the locale you can add this to it.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Could you give me one last tip? My website has 3 different languages and a contact page for each of these languages. I would like to do the language identification and that data be sent to a specific email for each especific language, it's possíble?

Comment: sure, how do you currently differentiate these 3 different contact pages?

Comment: 3 folders in resources | lang ->  'pt-br' (portuguese), 'en'(english) and 'de'(Germany), i use in many cases @if(app().getLocale() == 'pt-br') them make this or etc.
I made this in controller, but I don't know if that's the right way to do it. 
The code is like this:
        if (app()->getLocale() == 'pt-br' || app()->getLocale() == 'en') {
            Mail::send(new FaleConosco($contato)); <-destinatary cofigured in .env with SMTP//
        }else{
            Mail::to('email for the Germanu contact')->send(new FaleConosco($contato));
        }
Thank you anyway, it has helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When you pass parameters to the route, you should pass it as an array with keys, so that Laravel knows what the parameter is. In this case, you would do

```
<form id="frm-contato" class="site-form" action="{{ route('contato-enviar', ['lang' => app()->getLocale()]) }}" method="post">
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes

Comment: Thanks for the help man!